# HttpEntity with `application/xml` errors when moving from 1.0 to 2.0

Tags: java, xml, scala, akka, akka-http

I don't have a ton of background with akka, but has something changed in the way `HttpEntity` handles strings?

I'm am currently using akka-http 1.0, but would like to move up to 2.0 and start using the `Source.queue` functionality.  I am following the steps outlined in [this blog](http://kazuhiro.github.io/scala/akka/akka-http/akka-streams/2016/01/31/connection-pooling-with-akka-http-and-source-queue.html) that I was directed to from similar Stack Overflow question.  I have been able to implement everything from the blog post.  However, updating to 2.0 seems to have broken what I had in place for HttpEntity.  Currently I have following declaration inside of the `HttpRequest` in akka-http 1.0:

```
entity = HttpEntity(MediaTypes.`application/xml`, xml)
```

Where `xml` is a string that is created using XStream.
When I move over to 2.0 I receive warning from my IDE that it cannot resolve HttpEntity with with such signature, and that there is a type mismatch for the MediaTypes portion; expecting a ContentType.

Trying to pass the MediaType to ContentType with:

```
HttpEntity(ContentType(MediaTypes.`application/xml`), xml)
```

results with different Type mismatch; expecting `Binary` or `WithFixedCharset`, but finding `WithOpenCharset`.

Here is the whole code block for the HttpRequest for 1.0 that is currently working without issue:

```
httpReq = HttpRequest(method = HttpMethods.PUT,
        uri = itemUri, 
        entity = HttpEntity(MediaTypes.`application/xml`, xml), 
        headers = List(apiH))
```

Do I need to implement a custom serializer or something for xml strings with 2.0?

Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `text/xml` Content Type must indicate the charset so that the receiver of that information knows how to properly parse it.  If you are using UTF8, then you can simply use ContentTypes.`text/xml(UTF-8)` as this has a fixed charset.  If you wanted to use a different charset (like ISO-8859-1) then you could do something like this:

```
MediaTypes.`text/xml`.withCharset(HttpCharsets.`ISO-8859-1` )
```

Either way, you end up with a `WithCharset` as opposed to a `WithOpenCharset` and thus can use it on a response entity.